# Plotting two grouped variables side to side in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean

I Have a dataframe named `mydata`. Here's a sample of the relevant columns:

```
Backlog.Item.Type     Item.Created.To.Closed.Days   Item.Created.To.Finished.Days         
User Story            67                            84
Task                  14                            17
Task                  9                             10
Epic                  105                           NA
User Story            56                            59 
Bug                   5                             NA
```

Now, what I want to accomplish is the following: I want to take the mean for the `Item.Created.To.Closed.Days` column as well as for the `Item.Created.To.Finished.Days` column, grouped by `Backlog.Item.Type`, and then plot both next to eachother. To calculate the mean I use, which works:

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(Backlog.Item.Type) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Item.Created.to.Closed.Days),
               funs(mean(Item.Created.to.Closed.Days, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

For the plotting part, I have tried something like

```
mydata.long <- melt(mydata)

ggplot(mydata.long,
       aes(Backlog.Item.Type, value, fill = variable)) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. I should also note that I only want to plot the means for `Backlog.Item.Type == 'User Story'` and `Backlog.Item.Type == 'Task'` for both columns. Represented visually, this is what I want to accomplish:

[image]

Please excuses my horrible paint skills! I don't have any preference for colors or whatnot, I just need to get it done :D Thanks in advance, I hope I have been clear enough and formulated my question in a understandable manner!

Comment: Can you run dput(df) then add the output to your question?

Comment: what is count in the y-axis and how do you get its value?

Comment: @Tung My dataset consists of 2700 rows and 20 columns, so I don't think I'm able to do that! However, all the relevant columns and rows are described in my question. Or do you need any more?

Comment: @Antonis Sorry, I should have been more clear about that. I want the y-axis to display the amount of days: the mean values grouped by backlog item type corresponding to the Item.Created.To.Closed.Days and Item.Created.To.Finished.Days columns.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the graph you provided includes your whole data set and therefore should not be corresponding to the sample data you provided here is what you can do:

```
mydata=mydata %>% group_by(Backlog.Item.Type) %>% summarise(Item.Created.To.Closed.Days=
                        mean(Item.Created.To.Closed.Days,na.rm=T),
                        Item.Created.To.Finished=mean(Item.Created.To.Finished,na.rm=T)) 

mydata=mydata[complete.cases(mydata),]%>%melt()
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=Backlog.Item.Type,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess I should have added that in reality, my dataset consists of 2700 rows and about 20 columns. I edited your answer to: `mydata=mydata %>%
    group_by(Backlog.Item.Type) %>%
    summarise(Item.Created.To.Closed.Days=mean(Item.Created.To.Closed.Days,na.rm=T),Item.Created.To.Finished=mean(Item.Created.To.Finished,na.rm=T))

mydata=mydata[complete.cases(mydata),]%>%melt()%>%rename("count"="value")

ggplot(mydata,aes(x=Backlog.Item.Type,y=count,fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")`

Comment: Using this however I get a lot of errors: `object 'Item.Created.To.Closed.Days' not found`, `Error in rename(., count = "value") : unused argument (count = "value")` and `Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, fill`

Comment: well it runs ok here. I edited the answer check if it runs now. It is a bit simplified, the y-axis for instance is now labelled 'value', but you can easily rename it.